# How do I create a GOOGLE API script to pull data by the hour?

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

Essentially what I want to do is run this script every hour to pull in data from the last hour only and then the script will run again an hour later.  I want this script to pull all data associated with that last hour and then onwards for every hour of the day. How would I do this as I am only seeing a filter that can do this but I have read that it will only pull a sample and then filter on the hour from that sample.

```
   def get_report(analytics):

       return analytics.reports().batchGet(
          body={
              'reportRequests': [
               {
               '    viewId': VIEW_ID,
                       'dateRanges': [{'startDate': 
                                      '1dayAgo','endDate':'today'}],
     'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:uniquepageviews'},
                    {'expression': 'ga:timeonpage'},
                    {'expression': 'ga:entrances'},
                    {'expression': 'ga:exits'},
                    {"expression": "ga:pageviews"}
                    ],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dimension97'},
                    {'name': 'ga:dimension69'},
                    {'name': 'ga:dateHourMinute'},
                    ]

                   }]
            }
        ).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a sched module. It is possible to save the following code into a file and then execute it.

There are options for keeping the script running: terminal window, tmux session, background process, etc.

I used to use cron a lot but have changed to using the Python sched module. It can be easier to troubleshoot.

Save this code into a file.
execute `chmod 755 <myfile.py>`
Then run the script: `./myfile.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sched
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create a scheduler instance.
scheduler = sched.scheduler(timefunc=time.time)

def reschedule(interval: dict=None):
    """Define how often the action function will run.
    Pass a dict interval {'hours': 1} to make it run every hour.
    """
    interval = {'minutes': 1} if interval is None else interval
    # Get the current time and remove the seconds and microseconds.
    now = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    # Add the time interval to now
    target = now + timedelta(**interval)
    # Schedule the task
    scheduler.enterabs(target.timestamp(), priority=0, action=get_report)

def get_report(analytics=None):
    # replace the print call with the code execute the Google API call
    print(time.ctime())

    reschedule() # Reschedule so it runs again.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reschedule() # start

    try:
        scheduler.run(blocking=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopped.')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Tue Oct 29 22:35:00 2019
Tue Oct 29 22:36:00 2019
Stopped.
```

Comment: I will compare this to cronjobs thank you this is great help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you said "run this script every hour", [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is your best shot. It is just straightforward. And you don't need to mess with the logic responsible for interacting with google.

Basically, you define the schedule using cron expression, and specify the path of your script, cron daemon(crond) executes the script per the schedule.

This is an example cronjob entry:

```
# in terminal, type crontab -e. assume current user has enough permissions(read,write,execute file etc) to do the things they want.
5 * * * * python google_analytics.py
```

This means at minute 5 every hour, cron daemon will execute command: python google_analytics.py

This will be your new friend: https://crontab.guru/

In windows it's called scheduled tasks but the idea is the same.